# Prevent accidential creation of "backslash" filenames on Linux?

Tags: linux, path

After years of working on Windows, at work I am frequently saving files in the wrong location by typing `C:\tmp\filename.doc`. Where on Windows this would have created a hierachy

```
C:\
 '-- tmp\
      '-- filename.doc
```

on Linux this creates

```
/
 '-- current/
      '-- working/
           '-- directory/
                '-- C:\tmp\filename.doc
```

since backward slashes have no special meaning here.

Is there any feature that would allow me to intercept such accidential uses and either reject the file name outright or translate the backward slashes to forward slashes?

Comment: Do you need a system-wide solution? Or may it be only about what you *type* in a shell? What shell then?

Comment: Backslashes usually have special meaning, even on Linux. How did you create the file? Depending on what commands you used you might be able to "just" use an alias.

Comment: @Seth The creation of this file name works from GUI "save file" dialogs, shells (`touch 'C:\tmp\filename.doc'`) and Emacs (`C-x C-w C:\tmp\filename.doc`). At least on OpenSuse it thus doesn't seem to have a special meaning, at least not with regard to file names.

Comment: @Seth: On Linux, backslashes only have special meaning in the shell command language (and various text-based config languages) – they are not special in file names themselves.

Comment: @grawity correct but it's common to work with a shell and it's not uncommon that it will interpret strings handed to it. So depending on how you do it and what characters are included it certainly can happen. An easy example would be `touch this\nfile` which in my case strips the `\` unless it's in single quotes which requires the inclusion of `\\n` if you want to remove it. So the general statement "backslashes have no meaning" is wrong. Hence the question how those files are created. The example with touch includes single quotes, otherwise the path would be changed.

Comment: My most frequent use case is Emacs; There I have solved it meanwhile by adding an `advice` to `read-file-name`.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could change your keyboard layout to swap the position of the `/` and `\` keys; that's the only way I can think of to do what you're asking, since backslash has a special meaning of its own. However, that wouldn't really address your problem. Simply using slashes instead of backslashes wouldn't result in a correct file location since any path beginning with `C:` would in Linux be relative to the current working directory, anyway.

The correct solution is to slow down and come off autopilot for long enough to develop file naming habits that are appropriate to the system you're on--the differences extend far beyond which path separator to use. In my case, I'm primarily a Linux user who occasionally uses the Windows command line. In Windows, I have to slow down a bit to think about what I'm typing and ensure that I get it right.

Comment: While it wouldn't result in a correct location, `C:/my/file` would at least generate an error message about the non-existant folder `C:`.